# How to populate dropdown list at selection element with values from Google sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with custom HTML form. The form contains `<selection>` element.
Like this

```html
<select id="category_name"  name="category_name" class="control" style="width:150px;height:20px;margin:10px 0 10px 0;">
<option value="" selected></option>
</select>
```

I'm getting values from the sheet

```js
function getCategory() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);  
  let list = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  return list;  
}
```

And then I'm populating this selection with expected values in HTML file

```js
(function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function (selectList) {
            var select = document.getElementById("category_name");
            for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.val = selectList[i][0];
              option.text = selectList[i][0];
              select.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).getCategory();
      }());
```

It looks like list was populated well, but when I choice some item from selection it returns blank value after form submitting.
Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are not setting the `<option>` **value** correctly: `val` is not a valid attribute. Because of this, no value is added to each `<option>` and they are not submitted.

#### Solution:

Set the option value like this:

```js
option.value = selectList[i][0];
```

#### Using Option constructor:

Of course, using the Option constructor would also work:

```js
var option = new Option(selectList[i][0], selectList[i][0]);
```

#### Reference:

- [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement)
- [Option()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

Answer (score 0):

I use this a lot:

```
function updateSelect(vA,id){
  var id=id || 'sel1';
  var select = document.getElementById(id);
  select.options.length = 0; 
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);//Option(text, value);
      }
    }
```

[new option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)